# Powershell setting Excel cell value where Data Validation is ON

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a protected spreadsheet with some cells having Data Validation ON. I want to write legal values to these cells using Powershell.

Attempting saomething like:

```
$Worksheet.Item($col,$row)=$value
```

Always returns:

> Exception setting "Item": "The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only.
>
> To modify a protected cell or chart, first remove protection using the
>   Unprotect Sheet command (Review tab, Changes group). You may be
>   prompted for a password." At H:\scripts\ecmTrack_Shell.ps1:81 char:27
>   +         $WSheet.Cells.Item <<<< ($col,$row)=$value
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterParameterizedPropertySetValueTI

Found similar issue being addressed at [Use VBA to change value of cell with data validation applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979055/use-vba-to-change-value-of-cell-with-data-validation-applied), but don't see how this approach can apply to PShell since no types are being declared.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, now that I realized to address the cell by ($row,$col) instead of ($col,$row) and thus am pointing to the correct cell, this no longer appears to be an issue.